# most widely used python web app deployment style

Tags: python, apache, nginx, wsgi, fastcgi

I wonder which option is more stable (leaving performance aside) and is more widely used (I assume the widely used one is the most stable):

- apache -> mod_wsgi
- apache -> mod_fcgid
- apache -> mod_proxy_ajp
- apache -> mod_proxy_http

for a project that will serve REST services with small json formatted input and output messages and web pages, up to 100 req/s. Please comment on apache if you think nginx etc. is more suitable.

Thanks.

Comment: I would not be surprised if the most widely used is still cgi-bin. Widely used does not make it the best. (I guess it is stable though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100 req/s is not that hard to achieve these days.

Consider the deployment that your framework recommends. Zope for instance, has a decent webserver built in, so mod_proxy_http is good deployment.

Since wsgi came to fruition, it has become the preferred mechanism for many frameworks, and they now the builtin web servers are only suitable for development.

Regardless of what you deploy with now, it's important to be able to switch/add parts of the stack as necessary - do you want a reverse proxy for static content in there somwhere? You may not need one if you use nginx as it can serve static content from memcached quite well.

Summary: use wsgi

Comment: yes I was thinking I can use apache for that also. For wsgi, do your recommend directly using mod_wsgi or fcgi and flup ? I dont know exactly why but I had a feeling like mod_wsgi is not much matured. I can be completely wrong.

Comment: @mete, mod_wsgi runs fine for months at a time _at least_. I haven't found any problems using it. If you find a particular type of content that doesn't work properly you can always get apache to rewrite those urls to a different handler

Comment: @mete, For a new development it doesn't make sense to use flup. Build your system on one of the existing frameworks - Django, web2py, pylons, etc.

Comment: ok. thanks for recommendation. which is better, to map a single service to a single wsgi instance in apache or do the mapping inside the wsgi instance ?

Answer (score 2):

`apache` -> `mod-wsgi` is currently the "recommended" solution. But it also depends on your needs quite a bit.

There is quite a difference between running 1 heavy application versus 1 light aplication or many light applications.

Personally my preferred setup is still `nginx` -> `apache` -> `mod_wsgi` with multiple apache servers for heavy sites.

Comment: thanks for answer. what does nginx in front of apache do ? for static files ?

Comment: @mete, nginx can do rudimentary load balancing

Comment: @mete: simple load balancing, failover and static files.